# How to get the url of the last post, i just published using xmlrpc

Tags: python, wordpress

Is there a quick way to get the url of the last published post, just after publishing it

```
wp = Client('web site', ..., ...)
wp.call(GetPosts())
wp.call(GetUserInfo())

post = WordPressPost()
post.title =  'Test'
post.content = 'Test'
post.terms_names = 'Test'
post.comment_status = 'open'
post.post_status = 'publish'
wp.call(NewPost(post))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `NewPost()` returns the Post Id on success.

> Returns: ID of the newly-created blog post (an integer).

See: https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/methods.html#wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts.NewPost

```
post_id = wp.call(NewPost(post));
```

Comment: Thanks, can you also let know how to get the url of the post with post id?

Comment: You need to get the post `wp.call(GetPost(post_id));` which will return the `WordPressPost` instance... Everything is on the documentation, have a look: https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/wordpress.html#WordPressPost

Comment: Post URL can be retrieved such way:                                                       
```my_latest_post = wp.call(GetPost(post_id));
link = my_latest_post.link```